# Problema al bajar un .zip de un FTP con C# ( .NET )

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, zip

Estoy teniendo un problema al descargar un archivo .zip del servidor FTP.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es, buscar en el servidor los archivos .zip que necesito y descargarlos o bajarlos a mi ordenador, en una carpeta local y descomprimirlos.

Adjunto imagen del lo que tengo en el servidor FTP, el .zip resaltado en amarillo es el que tengo que descargar y descomprimir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el servidor los archivos .zip están bien generados, pero cuando los descargo, estos están corruptos, no me deja descomprimirlos.

Adjunto imagen del archivo .zip ya en una carpeta local
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando intenta descomprimirlo me lanza el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Antes me generaba la carpeta en la que se descomprimía y me lanzaba otro error, la carpeta que me generaba quedaba vacía. No logre volver a esa instancia)

Adjunto el código que realice para esto:

```
// Descargo el Zip
BajarZipDelFTP($"{camino}{pedido}", $@".\{vendedor}\", user, pass);
                        
// Descomprimo el zip
string zipPath = $@".\{vendedor}\{pedido}";
// el pedido contiene el nombre del archivo que voy a bajar
pedido = pedido.Replace(".zip", "");
string extractPath = $@".\{vendedor}\{pedido}";

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath); //En esta linea rompe
```

El codigo del BajarZipDelFTP es:

```
public static void BajarZipDelFTP(string ruta, string local, string usuario, string pass)
{
    // Conecta al servidor ftp
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ruta);
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, pass);
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ftpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

    string res = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Guardarlo localmente con la extensión .zip
    string ficLocal = Path.Combine(local, Path.GetFileName(ruta));
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ficLocal, false, Encoding.UTF8);
    
    sw.Write(res);
    sw.Close();

    reader.Close();
    
    /*
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ruta);
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, pass);
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;
    StreamWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        stream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Default);
        writer = new StreamWriter(local, false, Encoding.Default); // en esta linea rompe
        writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Close();
        reader.Close();
        writer.Close();
    }*/
}
```

Lo que esta comentado en este método es una forma que encontré en internet pero también me tira error en la linea indicada.

Como seguro se dieron cuenta, uso variables para las rutas del servidor y otras cosas mas, ya me fije con el depurador y me genera bien las rutas y demás, además de que se conecta al servidor y descarga justo el archivo que necesito.

Ya llevo varios días intentando solucionarlo, buscando en internet, probando diferentes maneras y no encuentro una solución.

Espero poder encontrar aquí la solución al problema.

Desde ya le agradezco a todo aquel que se tome su tiempo de en ver esto.
Saludos

Comment: Logre dejar con el error que me daba antes (cambie en el BajarZipDelFTP la linea: 
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ficLocal, false, Encoding.UTF8);  por la siguiete:
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ficLocal, false, Encoding.Default)
Y me lanza el siguiente error:
;System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'El número de entradas esperado en el registro de fin de directorio central no se corresponde con el número de entradas del directorio central.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre solucionar el problema dado al bajar el zip del FTP.

El error estaba en el BajarZipDelFTP, a la hora de bajar el zip.
Al final me quedo así:

```
public static void BajarZipDelFTP(string ruta, string local, string usuario, string pass)
{
    // Conecta al servidor ftp
    FtpWebRequest objRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ruta);
    objRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, pass);
    objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    // Guardarlo localmente con la extensión .zip
    FtpWebResponse objResponse = (FtpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int len = 0;
    string ficLocal = Path.Combine(local, Path.GetFileName(ruta));
    FileStream objFS = new FileStream(ficLocal, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);

    while ((len = objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        objFS.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    objFS.Close();
    objResponse.Close();
}
```

El resto funciona correctamente, incluso lo descomprime bien.

Comment: En 20 horas aproximadamente, recuerda marcar esta respuesta como aceptada. Bien jugado. :D

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!! Tenía exactamente el mismo problema que tú, los zip bajaban corruptos y con tusolución ya me funciona perfectamente. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @Ambros bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Esto no es un foro al uso, la forma de agradecer una respuesta es votandola favoramente, y no usar la zona de respuestas para comentarios que no son una respuesta. Por el momento te he convertido tu respuesta a un comentario, pero por favor tenlo en cuenta para el futuro